# how sku description linking to instance google cloud platform billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, instance, billing

I want to see how the payment of each service related to an instance is expressed
how i know which service is related to which instance
for example: service: Compute Engine the sku:Load Balanced HTTP/HTTPS Request
which instance this service related??

Comment: Are you asking about the Billing Catalog API? https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-billing-catalog-api/

Comment: i export billing to bigquery and i want to know which sku description run on which instance

Comment: i export billing to bigquery and i want to know which sku description run on which instance

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you visit the following links [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-cloud-billing-catalog-api-gcp-pricing-in-real-time)[[2]](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api) providing more details about Cloud Billing Catalog API, which helps you gain programmatic, real-time access to authoritative Google Cloud Platform (GCP) list pricing and how to get the list of SKUs for a service.

If you would like to have more features and if the provided solution doesn’t fulfill your needs. I would suggest that you submit a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). Google will consider the need based on its feasibility, or the number of customers who ask for it as we strive on improving our products and your feedback helps us do just that.